What does "I bought out the house" mean in this context?
In the movie "Rear Window" the main character is spending the last couple of weeks in his house because of his broken leg. His girlfriend visits his house and wears a very expensive dress. He asks her about the occasion this dress if worn for.

Lisa: It's opening night of the last week of L.B Jefferies in a cast.
Jeff: Well, I haven't noticed a big demand for tickets or anything.
Lisa Ah, that's because I bought out the house.

Does "buy out" in this context mean...

to purchase full ownership of something from someone or a group. We liked the company, so we borrowed a lot of money and bought it out. Carl bought out the owners of the company.
(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002)

...and "house":

house (noun):
13. (Theatre) the audience in a theatre or cinema (Collins English Dictionary)

In this case this would mean that she purchased all of the tickets from the audience in a theatre or cinema to watch the metaphorical last week of Jeff's last week in a cast.

I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about about very unusual / non-idiomatic phrasing involving punning that might well not even be grasped by native Anglophones. It's not really relevant to "learning English".

@FumbleFingers Completely unfair because to buy out the house doesn't change its meaning. It's only the overall dialogue that's the joke. So, no, it should NOT be closed. And my answer stands even without the explanation for the joke. The passage is the joke, not the phrase. The phrase is relevant. Please stop trying to judge this kind of thing which is legit.

A product or tickets to a commercial performance can sell out, but to buy out all of any such offerings never has had any currency. You can only "buy out" an individual who currently owns part or all of something you want ownership / control of. But the "performance" here is metaphorical in the first place, and there aren't even any metaphorical "sellers" of "tickets". The fact that's additional punning around cast isn't relevant, though. Everything about the exchange is completely one-off wordplay, of little or no relevance to any future constructions a learner might meet.

@FumbleFingers Not everything has been already said or written. So your entire previous comment is really iffy. One can imagine a very rich man in love with an actress, so he goes to the theater where she is in a play and buys out the house.

what is this discussion? how is it not idiomatic to buy out the house? it looks like OP also answered their own question correctly with dictionary definitions :)

I'm with FumbleFingers.
In general English, to 'buy out the house' ought to mean, Lisa purchased all the tickets…
Here, the one and only clue is Jeff's 'I haven't noticed a big demand…'.
How are those two anything but diametrically opposed?

Yeah, those definitions were close enough that you've got the right idea. The definition of "buy out" you found is focused on the world of finance and business. This usage is more like a "buyer's point of view" corollary to the notion of "selling out," defined in #3 here:

3a: to sell all the available tickets for
(sold out the concert)
b: to sell all of (the merchandise was quickly sold out)

For instance, you might find that a shirt you wanted to buy was "sold out," i.e. the store had sold all of them, or that a movie screening you wanted to attend was "sold out." Using "buy out" this way is pretty much limited to shows, simply because there could be a motivation. (It's rare to want to purchase all available supply of a product, and when such situations come up, for some reason it's more common to say e.g. "I bought up all the copies of today's paper from the newsstand so he won't see the article about him" or "I bought up all the dresses like this one so no one will be wearing the same dress as me to the wedding.")
But especially in the past (but to some degree still today), those with the means might want to see a play or movie in privacy, and buy all the tickets to a particular show (see the movie Annie in which the wealthy Daddy Warbucks treats the orphan to a private screening).
Meanwhile, for "house," 7a:

"a building or part of a building where people gather for a specified kind of activity (a movie house; the local coffee house; a house cocktail [=a cocktail whose recipe was created by the bar, restaurant, etc. at which it is served])

... is perhaps closer than 7c, "the audience in a theater or concert hall." Lisa didn't have to purchase tickets directly from any audience members, as people might purchase shares of a company from shareholders in a corporate buyout; one could "buy out the house" simply by making a deal directly with "the house," i.e. the theater.

This is part of a joke: cast and cast. And here, house is more likely a theater for plays. But it works with either movie house or playhouse, both of which are theaters. If she bought out the house, she bought all available tickets. It's a joke: cast and cast. Get it? Anyway, it's playhouse or moviehouse. Either one works.

@Andy Bonner I guess in this case this is a more appropriate definition of "but out" for this context:
4. verb To purchase all of a particular item or thing that is available. A noun or pronoun can be used between "buy" and "out."
That toy is so popular that it's been bought out all over town!

@StaticBounce What? But out? No, bought out the tickets to viewing him in his apartment AS IF he were part of a cast, when in fact, he has a cast ON HIS LEG. Do you see the joke now? The point being that Lisa is the only audience he has...[anything you can purchase, can be bought out. in that sense, it means all of the product or thing]

I've heard of it in the context of buying out a hotel for an event.

The last paragraph is totally meaningless as Lisa didn't buy anything.  "Lisa didn't have to purchase tickets directly from any audience members, as people might purchase shares of a company from shareholders in a corporate buyout; one could "buy out the house" simply by making a deal directly with "the house," i.e. the theater"

The house refers to the playhouse, theater.
It  means the character Lisa bought all the tickets that were available for purchase.
It you buy all the tickets to a performance, you buy them out.
The entire passage is a JOKE.
He has a cast on his leg. He is not in a cast of characters/ actors.
It is the last week he will be in a cast. [joke]
She has all the seats. She's the one who has privileged access to him and his only visitor. I can't remember the movie exactly but I think she is his main "admirer". She is the only one with a ticket. Ha ha.

But this sense of theater from your definition describes the place with actors on a stage and not a movie theater AFAIK. Am I right? The context regards the cinema (or a part of the cinema from Andy Bonner's definition), right?

@StaticBounce It could also be a movie theatre. I just assumed it was a play.  But in general, house is more of a place where plays are shown, not movies. L.B. Jefferies in a cast=his leg is in a cast. cast is also the list of characters in a play OR movie. I just realized this is a joke.

"It's opening night of the last week of L.B Jefferies in a cast" So, it means it is the first night of the last week his leg will be in a cast. They are joking. But house here is more likely play, than movie. Then, the tickets thing takes the meaning of cast as characters in a play and talks about selling out the house. See? :) He is literally in a cast. He is not acting. That's the joke part. In other words, his love interest bought all the tickets. She is his audience.

@StaticBounce Oh dear, I should have clarified. Yes, this language could just as easily be about stage plays; in fact, the notion of a particular actor being an attraction might be more relevant there: "Last week to see so-and-so (because they'll be replaced by another actor next week." And yes, the whole thing is obviously an extended metaphor; there is no actual show.

OP has asked to explain the scene from the movie,  Rear window

Lisa: It's opening night of the last week of L.B Jefferies in a cast.
Jeff: Well, I haven't noticed a big demand for tickets or anything.
Lisa Ah, that's because I bought out the house.
In this case this would mean that she purchased all of the tickets from the audience in a theatre or cinema to watch the metaphorical last week of Jeff's last week in a cast.

In the 1954 movie "Rear Window," L.B. Jefferies, a photojournalist, recuperates from a broken leg. His girlfriend, Lisa Carol Fremont, visits him, wearing an expensive dress.
The dialogue is a clever pun (play on words). If you try to check a real meaning, it doesn't make any sense.
Let's consider what the pun. (Opening, cast, bought out the house) means (explanation in bold and italics):
Lisa: "It's opening night of the last week of L.B. Jefferies in a cast.".
(Jeff's leg's plaster will be removed soon, and Lisa celebrates it by wearing an expensive dress. It doesn't refer to a movie because Jeffries is a photojournalist and not a movie star)
Jeff: "Well, I haven't noticed a big demand for tickets or anything.".
(Jeff humorously asks why there is no rush for the show)
Lisa: "Ah, that's because I bought out the house.".
(Lisa implies she's the only audience for Jeff's recovery, because she has purchased all the tickets.)

Yes, bought up every seat, but not "from the audience", from the theater directly.  The Collins definition is misleading, as are several other dictionaries. The house is the area of the theater where patrons would be, and it can be used metonymically of the audience.

Is there a doctor in the house?

Could be paraphrased as "Is there anyone in the audience who is a doctor?"  When someone in the theater needs emergency medical attention, the manager stops the show and asks that question.
Compare:

It was standing room only. The house was sold out.

out there is a preposition used as a phrasal verb particle meaning "entirely" or "completely".
The flip side of the transaction is "buy out".

Well, you have to start with the fact that this conversation is a joke/flirtation.  He is in the last week of wearing a plaster of paris cast, she is dressed up to see him.
So, her first pun (joke) is to turn a plaster of paris cast into a cast member in a theater. He goes with the joke but points out the low turn out (complains about being unliked).   She ripostes by saying that she bought out the house (i.e. is keeping him to herself).
In context it would mean that the reason he hasn’t had visitors is because she has been warning people away either for privacy or health reasons. Given his personality in the movie, I would say that was a little white lie and that he hit it on the mark — nobody is seeing him because he’s a bit of an ass.
In summary “bought out the house” is a term that means you’ve arranged for exclusive usage of a venue, generally a theater or restaurant, but can be used for other venues or circumstances as well.
